# Permission issue with tar a file on mounted filesystem

Tags: permissions

I am taring a folder with permissions & owner details intact but while untar it to a normal directory its permissions are there but if I untar it on a mounted filesystem ( i.e mounting a SDcard partition on /mnt and untar files to /mnt) the ownership are changed. Its giving 1001 in owner and group names.

$ mount | grep /mnt

/dev/sdd2 on /mnt type ext3 (rw)

Comment: Please run `mount | grep /mnt` in a terminal and add the output to your question via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/911721/edit). Your SDcard partition should be mounted  when you run the command.

Comment: `1001`  looks like a user-id rather than a user-name. `ls`-command will list user-id instead of  user-name if the user does not exist. `/mnt` is normally owned by user `root`, maybe this is the problem. I'd try to change ownership of `/mnt` temporary to check if the problem persists. I think the program you use to untar does a trick to be able to write to `/mnt`.

Comment: That was a bit inaccurate, `ls`-command will list the user-id instead of the user-name if a user-name does not exist. BTW, you can check your own user-id with `echo $UID`.

Comment: @mook765 thanks for the comment. Now i got that 1001 belongs to a user-Id of pc where i tar the file. I am extracting it to different pc thats why is showing in numbers.

Comment: @mook765 but the problem is i am using sudo for untar the compressed file that means it will preserve the permissions and same- owner flags, then how come i am getting different owner while extracting to normal directory and /mnt. Is there any way to change it.

Comment: What is the command you use to untar? do you use sudo when you untar to a "normal" directory?

Comment: @mook765 no for normal directory i use "tar -pxjvf  file.tar.bz2 -C  /dir/"

Comment: Try to add the `--no-same-permissions`-option to the command, I'm just right now not sure if that will change the ownership of the extracted files to `root` or to yourself. Never tried that myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man tar`:

```
 --no-same-permissions
       apply the user's umask when extracting permissions from the archive
       (default for ordinary users)

-p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
       extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)
```

So, if you have to use root-privileges to be able to extract to `/mnt`, just add the `--no-same-permissions`-option to your command. The `p`-option has to been removed from the command, so in your case, the command

```
sudo tar --no-same-permissions -xjvf file.tar.bz2 -C /mnt
```

should do what you want. All files and folders will be owned by yourself.